# difference between "inherit" and "process pipe child"

Tags: node.js

I spawn a shell to read from input then execute

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const child = spawn('while :;do read a;$a;done', [], { shell: true,stdio:'inherit' })
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
})
```

with `stdio:'inherit'`, it will consume 100% cpu. But if I remove `stdio:'inherit'` and add `process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin)`, it works perfectly

the doc says

```
'inherit' - equivalent to [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]
```

So what's the actual meaning of `inherit` and the difference between them

Answer (score 15):

Little late to answer sorry, but for anybody else who is looking... I was confused about this too at first and the documentation is a bit light.

`inherit` means the stdios (stdin, stdout, stderr) for the parent process will be handed off to the child process. So if the stdin on child process is set to `inherit`, any key presses will target the child process and not the parent.

`pipe` means that the stdios for both the parent and child are mapped together. However accessing piped data through those pips is accessed through events. So if you spawn a child process with a stdout of `pipe`, you can access any output of that process through the use of `childProcess.stdout.on('data', callbakFn)`

Comment: does it have anything to do with {silent: false|true} property ? I know stdio array variant overrides aforementioned property of silent , but I am trying to find connection between and I think I fail . Anyone reply would be highly appreciated !